# syncing passwords across several devices

Tags: sync, password-management, cloud

Is it possible to sync  a change to a password across several devices? When I change my password to a site such as SE my device asks me if I want the new password to be saved and automatically applied in future. But then when I change my device I need to remember the new password. Is there a way of syncing passwords between several devices the same way a file is synced by cloud services such as DropBox?

Answer (score 3):

This could depend on what Browser you are using. For example, I use chrome and am signed into chrome. When i change a password chrome updates the saved password for the site. When I go to another device, i go to the logon page from chrome and it auto-fills my correct information.

Comment: I use chrome too but have not noticed that it saves password from a machine to next. Each new machine requires entering the password. Is there a password management system that one needs to activate?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LastPass?   Works on PC, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS.   Does exactly what you are trying to do.   I think in order to have it work properly on handheld/portable devices you will need the enterprise version (which is a few dollars a year), but worth every penny IMHO.

http://lastpass.com

Comment: A free opensource program you can also try, if you want to go that route, is [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)